# foreach vs ForEach-Object -Parallel in powershell - what is wrong?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage, foreach-object

I am confused with ForEach-Object -Parallel. The following code has $blobs array with more than 2000 blobs. With the regular **foreach** I can print the names of each blob  without a problem. Then using the **ForEach-Object -Parallel** just after the first foreach, nothing is printed. Why ?

```
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
           Write-Host    $blob.Name
}

# Use parallel processing to process blobs concurrently
$blobs|ForEach-Object -Parallel {
         param (
             $blob)
    
        Write-Host $blob.Name 
} -ThrottleLimit 300
```

Comment: What if you do `$blobs | For-Each Object { Write-Host $blob.Name }` (i.e. without `-Parallel`?)

Answer (score 8):

The script block passed to a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* call - whether or not you use `-Parallel` - receives its (pipeline) input *implicitly*, via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) (aka `$PSItem`). (In other words: there's no need for or point in declaring a *parameter*):

```bash
$blobs |
  ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $_.Name  # $_ implicitly refers to the pipeline input object at hand
  }
```

- By contrast, the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement* requires a *self-chosen iterator variable* (such as `$blob` in your example).

  - Perhaps confusingly, `foreach` is also an *alias* of the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, and it is the *syntactic context* that decides whether `foreach` refers to the language *statement* or the *cmdlet*.
- Note that the `-ThrottleLimit` parameter controls how many threads are allowed *at a time*. For CPU-bound operations, it doesn't make sense to specify a number higher than the available CPU cores; only for operations that are network-bound, I/O-bound, or wait for events do higher numbers make sense.
- With respect to the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, while `$_` is used both with or without `-Parallel`, there is an important difference with respect to referencing *variables* from the caller's scope:

  - With `-Parallel`, you need the [`$using:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3#the-using-scope-modifier) scope; e.g.:

    ```bash
    $foo = 'bar'
    # Note the $using:foo reference.
    # *Without* -Parallel, use just $foo
    # -> 'bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'
    1..3 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { $using:foo + $_ }
    ```